# Positioned Grid View pictures dont appear in cell

Tags: android, gridview, imageview

I made a mini game with images. I want to use the grid layout margin as board to keep dynamic the size. Now i have a problem with the pictures when I appear them they appear in full size and not in the grid cell.

Here is my activity main xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.codes.logicgarden.MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp">



                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/im00"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_row="0"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                    android:onClick="dropIn"
                    android:tag="0" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/im01"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                android:onClick="dropIn"
                android:tag="1" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/im02"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                android:onClick="dropIn"
                android:tag="2" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/im03"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="3"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                android:onClick="dropIn"
                android:tag="3" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/im04"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="4"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                android:onClick="dropIn"
                android:tag="4" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/im10"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                android:onClick="dropIn"
                android:tag="5" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/im11"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                android:onClick="dropIn"
                android:tag="6" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/im12"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                android:onClick="dropIn"
                android:tag="7" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/im13"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="3"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                android:onClick="dropIn"
                android:tag="8" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/im14"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="4"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                android:onClick="dropIn"
                android:tag="9" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/im20"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                android:onClick="dropIn"
                android:tag="10" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/im21"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                android:onClick="dropIn"
                android:tag="11" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/im22"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                android:onClick="dropIn"
                android:tag="12" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/im23"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="3"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                android:onClick="dropIn"
                android:tag="13" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/im24"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="4"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_row="2"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                android:onClick="dropIn"
                android:tag="14" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/im30"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_row="3"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                android:onClick="dropIn"
                android:tag="15" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/im31"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_row="3"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                android:onClick="dropIn"
                android:tag="16" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/im32"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_row="3"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                android:onClick="dropIn"
                android:tag="17" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/im33"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="3"
                android:layout_row="3"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                android:onClick="dropIn"
                android:tag="18" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/im34"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="4"
                android:layout_row="3"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                android:onClick="dropIn"
                android:tag="19" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/im40"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_row="4"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                android:onClick="dropIn"
                android:tag="20" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/im41"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_row="4"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                android:onClick="dropIn"
                android:tag="21" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/im42"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_row="4"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                android:onClick="dropIn"
                android:tag="22" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/im43"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="3"
                android:layout_row="4"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                android:onClick="dropIn"
                android:tag="23" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/im44"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="4"
                android:layout_row="4"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                android:onClick="dropIn"
                android:tag="24" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/im50"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_row="5"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                android:onClick="dropIn"
                android:tag="25" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/im51"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_row="5"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                android:onClick="dropIn"
                android:tag="26" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/im52"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_row="5"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                android:onClick="dropIn"
                android:tag="27" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/im53"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="3"
                android:layout_row="5"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                android:onClick="dropIn"
                android:tag="28" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/im54"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="4"
                android:layout_row="5"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                android:onClick="dropIn"
                android:tag="29" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/im60"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_row="6"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                android:onClick="dropIn"
                android:tag="30" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/im61"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_row="6"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                android:onClick="dropIn"
                android:tag="31" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/im62"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_row="6"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                android:onClick="dropIn"
                android:tag="32" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/im63"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="3"
                android:layout_row="6"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                android:onClick="dropIn"
                android:tag="33" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/im64"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="4"
                android:layout_row="6"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/background_light"
                android:onClick="dropIn"
                android:tag="34" />

        </GridLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/playAgainLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/gridLayout"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
            android:visibility="invisible">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/winnerMessage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="204dp"
                android:onClick="playAgain"
                android:text="Play Again" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

How can i make when i click on the images they will appear in the grid view cell where they are assigned like in the editor and not original size?

The program working when the images have fix size but i want to make it dynamic to all platform.

[How should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uah6C.png)

[How appear in emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RIjX.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really use a gridView with a custom adapter. than you set the adapter with a click listener and thats it.

Because if you want to change something in the image you will only need to do it once and not 32 times.

here is a really nice tutorial that can get you started with https://www.raywenderlich.com/127544/android-gridview-getting-started

Comment: I sorted the problem android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" i changed wrap_content to 1dp now working. Thank you for the link i am looking forward to do the tutorial!